# Set valued map and equality of sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, set-theory

Let $K$ a compact of $\mathbb{R}^p$ and $t\mapsto F(t)$ a set-valued function such that $F(t)$ is a closed set of $\mathbb{R}^p$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

Is it true that
$$
\{t: F(t)\cap K\neq \emptyset\} = \bigcup_{n\ge 1} \{t:F(t)\cap V_n\neq \emptyset\} \qquad (*)
$$
where $V_n=\{x,d(x,K)<1/n\}$ ?

Because what I find is that :
$$
\{t: F(t)\cap K\neq \emptyset\} = \bigcap_{n\ge 1} \{t:F(t)\cap V_n\neq \emptyset\}
$$
and I don't understand the argument to show $(*)$ use in page 72 of Georges, Exercices in Integration, 1984 available [here](http://library.lol/main/B6787788D6E1D0EB2401B9A0E58C23F5).

proof:
$\subset$
If $t\in \{t: F(t)\cap K\neq \emptyset\}$ then let $x\in F(t)\cap K$ this means that $x\in V_n$ for all $n$ so $x\in F(t)\cap V_n$ for all $n$.

$\supset$ If $t\in \bigcap_{n\ge 1} \{t:F(t)\cap V_n\neq \emptyset\}$ then for all $n$ there is $x_n\in V_n\cap F(t)$.
Since $V_n\cap F(t)$ is bounded we can extract a converging subsequence $y_n \to y$. We have $d(y_n,K)<1/n$ for all $n$ so $y\in K$. Also $y\in F(t)$ so $y\in F(t)\cap K$ and $t\in  \{t: F(t)\cap K\neq \emptyset\}$.

Example for $(*)$.
Take $F(t)$ be the unit ball centered at $(t,0,\dots,0)$ and consider $K$ be the unit ball centered at $0$.
Then $\{t: F(t)\cap K\neq \emptyset\}=[-2,2]$.
$V_n$ are the ball centered at $0$ of radius $1+1/n$ and we have
$F(t)\cap V_n \neq \emptyset$ for $t\in [-2-1/n,2+1/n]$ so
$\bigcup_{n\ge 1} \{t:F(t)\cap V_n\neq \emptyset\}
=\bigcup_{n\ge 1} [-2-1/n,2+1/n]$ which is not $[-2,2]$... so there must be a typo in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little nitpick; you should say $V_1\cap F(t)$ is compact and $V_n\cap F(t)\subseteq V_1\cap F(t)$, i.e. $x_n\in V_1\cap F(t)$ for every $n$, so $(x_n)$ admits a convergent subsequence. You wrote: $x_n$ is in *a* bounded set for every $n$, and that is not enough to say $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence.

Other than that, I agree with you that: $\{t:F(t)\cap K\neq\emptyset\}=\bigcap_{n\ge1}\{t:F(t)\cap V_n\neq\emptyset\}$. The author **definitely** made a typo. My confidence in this comes from the following:

[image: Extract]

"If for *all* $n$, there exists $x_n\in...$" means the author is treating the union as an intersection. It is a typo: their text is correct, but their maths-formatting must have gone awry somehow.